# Avoid multiple users to update a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

Here is my problem. I am building a `react` app with `Spring Boot` as the back-end. My application is used by many users including many roles.

I need to disable a specific component if it is already accessed by another user. **A single user is allowed to edit the page with that component and it should be displayed as disabled for other users**. We are using MongoDB and token-based authetication.

I heard that this can be achieved by Firestore, but I have no idea about it. May I know what will be the best solution to achieve this functionality? I appreciate your help to find a solution for this.

Comment: So you're trying to allow editing one user by one so doesn't collide?

Comment: Yeah, it is like, I've some templates in my app. One user can edit this template at a time. If another user is trying to access it at the same time, that template should be disabled. Once the first user submitted the template, then the template will be enabled to other users.

Comment: This is a really broad topic making it an ill fit for Stack Overflow, but you're definitely gonna want to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to prevent multiple users from trying to update the document.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yeah, this is too broad. I found this as useful. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence